# Sprinboot backend and reactjs frontend FormData requst error

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, multipartform-data

My springboot model is this:

```
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    @Document(collection = "products")
    public class Product {
        @Id
        private String id;
        @NotEmpty(message = "name is mandatory")
        private String name;
        @NotEmpty(message = "price is mandatory")
        private int price;
        private MultipartFile file;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Data
    @Builder
    public class AddProductCommand implements Serializable {
        @TargetAggregateIdentifier
        private String id;
        @NotNull(message = "no product details were supplied")
        @Valid
        private Product product;
    
        public AddProductCommand(){
    
        }
    }
```

Since I have to send a MultipartFile from the reactjs, I must use FormData. I have tried the following:

```
    async handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    try {
        let product = new FormData();    
        product.append("name", this.state.name);
        product.append("price", this.state.price);
        product.append("file", this.state.file);
        let addProductCommand = new FormData();
        addProductCommand.append("product", product);
        const response = await axios.post(SELL_URL, addProductCommand , {
                headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
              }
          });
        this.clearState();
        event.target.reset();
        this.props.history.push("/buy"); 
    } catch (err) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    }
```

However, I got following error in the springboot:

```
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'addProductCommand' on field 'product': rejected value [[object FormData]]; codes [typeMismatch.addProductCommand.product,typeMismatch.product,typeMismatch.com.cognizant.user.core.models.Product,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [addProductCommand.product,product]; arguments []; default message [product]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.cognizant.user.core.models.Product' for property 'product'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.cognizant.user.core.models.Product' for property 'product': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

What have I missed and how should I fix this error?

Add controller code. I am trying to implement it as CQRS design. Here is the controller. I nedd to write more description not much code. Otherwise stackoverflow doesn't allow me do add more code :(.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/addProduct")
public class AddProductController {
    private final CommandGateway commandGateway;


 @Autowired
  public AddProductController(CommandGateway commandGateway) {
    this.commandGateway = commandGateway;
 
}

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<AddProductResponse> registerUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute AddProductCommand command) {
    var id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    command.setId(id);

    try {
        commandGateway.sendAndWait(command);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new AddProductResponse(id, "Product added successfully!"), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        var safeErrorMessage = "Error while processing add product request for id - " + id;
        System.out.println(e);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new AddProductResponse(id, safeErrorMessage), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
  }

 }
```

Comment: share your controller method also

Comment: Ths for your response. Pls check controller code.

Comment: can you try adding @ModelAttribute("product") to your controller

Comment: Thx @ModelAttribute("product")  solved the problem. If u wish to give it as an answer, pls do it.

Comment: nice :) sure I will add it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the above scenario, you are appending form data to the product key `addProductCommand.append("product", product);`
so in your controller, you should get the product entity. add this to your controller; `@ModelAttribute("product")`

```
public ResponseEntity<AddProductResponse> registerUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("product") AddProductCommand command)
```